# Best way to stop a Service bind with a ServiceConnection in an Activity in Android?

Tags: android, service, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-intent

I have a Service that is bind in my Activity with a ServiceConnection.
The Service starts when the Activity is created and stops in my BroadcastReceiver class and works great. Now, I will like to stop the Service after a give period. Being trying TimerTask in my Service class, but don't seems to be working correctly.

Any suggestion or solutions would be kindly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Timer also treated as independent Thread.so Context might be changed when you are trying to stop the Service.My Solution is get the Pid of Current service and kill the service using the Pid. android:process attribute will be specified in androidmanifest.xml.

Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill pid"); 
InputStream is = process.getInputStream();

this code works fine . try it once

Answer (score 0):

Declare a static in your App:

```
static Intent local_Intent;
```

On create of the App assign a new Intent for the service and bind to local_Intent:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    local_Intent = new Intent(this, yourAppService.class);
}
```

The assignment to local_Intent is remembered because local_Intent is static
When you want to start the service in your App

```
 startService(local_Intent);
```

When you want to stop the service in your App

```
 stopService(local_Intent);
```